# micronaut ssl: no netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64 in java.library.path

Tags: java, ssl, netty, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I am trying to configure SSL in micronaut application. I have configured the keystore and truststore and validated that certificates are valid. However while running the application I am getting below exception.

```
12:01:54.564 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty_tcnative', trying next name...
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:226)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:581)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:133)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:123)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultServerProvider(SslContext.java:110)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:457)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:72)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.<init>(NettyHttpServer.java:207)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$NettyHttpServerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1888)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2630)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2616)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2299)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2273)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1254)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:738)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:149)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:294)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:280)
    at example.Application.main(Application.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/netty_tcnative.dll
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:175)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:351)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative in java.library.path
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:371)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:363)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:341)
            ... 25 common frames omitted
12:01:54.570 [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl - Failed to load netty-tcnative; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable, unless the application has already loaded the symbols by some other means. See https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html for more information.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64, netty_tcnative_x86_64, netty_tcnative]
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:104)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:581)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:133)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:123)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultServerProvider(SslContext.java:110)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:457)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:72)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.<init>(NettyHttpServer.java:207)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$NettyHttpServerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1888)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2630)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2616)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2299)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2273)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1254)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:738)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:149)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:294)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:280)
    at example.Application.main(Application.java:9)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:226)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64.dll
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:175)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64 in java.library.path
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:351)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
            ... 24 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64 in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:371)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:363)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:341)
                ... 25 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_x86_64
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:226)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/netty_tcnative_x86_64.dll
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:175)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:351)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
            ... 24 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:371)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:363)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:341)
                ... 25 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:226)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/netty_tcnative.dll
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:175)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative in java.library.path
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:351)
            at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
            ... 24 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:371)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:363)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:341)
                ... 25 common frames omitted
12:01:54.571 [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl - Initialize netty-tcnative using engine: 'default'
12:01:54.573 [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl - Failed to initialize netty-tcnative; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable. See https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html for more information.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.version(I)I
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.version(Native Method)
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.initialize(Library.java:126)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.initializeTcNative(OpenSsl.java:586)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:150)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:123)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultServerProvider(SslContext.java:110)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:457)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.ssl.CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.build(CertificateProvidedSslBuilder.java:72)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.<init>(NettyHttpServer.java:207)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$NettyHttpServerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1888)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2630)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2616)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2299)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2273)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1254)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:738)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:149)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:294)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:280)
    at example.Application.main(Application.java:9)
```

Due to this, SSL is not enabled while running the application and I am getting below exception in logs while hitting the REST endpoint over https.

```
12:11:10.358 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Micronaut Server Error - No request state present. Cause: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:214)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1089)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:912)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:782)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:626)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:281)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1340)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1282)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
12:11:10.359 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Micronaut Server Error - No request state present. Cause: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:214)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1089)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:912)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:782)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:626)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:281)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1340)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1282)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

I am getting the response but that is over insecure connection.
How do I provide the `netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64` library so that I can establish the secure connection over https?

JAVA Version: jdk1.8.0_251
Micronaut version: 2.0.0

Comment: Are you able to share what do you have as dependencies in your build.gradle ?

Comment: Have you had a look at the netty-tcnative docs? https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html